# 1kg mass impacting at half light speed - effects?

Tags: classical-mechanics, nuclear-physics, plasma-physics

Such a mass would have kinetic energy approximating a 1 mega-tonne thermonuclear weapon. So, what would such an object do if it hit the Earth? We know how destructive such an energy release can be, but the 1kg mass would have massive directionality. Would it be less destructive? Would it dig a crater? Penetrate the crust? Or just dissipate in the mantle with little in the way of surface destruction? or...?

Comment: https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/  covers this pretty well.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Post it as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

While I have never conducted such an experiment (yet), I conjecture it will be the energy of the projectile what will determine the results. It will also bring momentum, but this would be comparable roughly to three A380 jets at cruise speed, so it probably would not change much on the result.

The projectile would start evaporating already when passing through atmosphere, radiating a broad electromagnetic spectrum and generating a massive blast wave. I can not tell how soon it would shatter and atomize, but it would probably not penetrate much of Earth's crust before it does. After this, the energy would be transferred to radiation and creation of really hot plasma; the rest would be perhaps similar to any thermonuclear weapon test as you conjecture, with reduced radioactive fallout.

Even though, this this kind of experiment is probably illegal in most countries.

Comment: I imagine it would be similar to a monstrously powerful particle beam from an accelerator?

Comment: Perhaps, but without much of the exotic physics given by the particles travelling at (1-10Ȇ c,

Comment: ... at (1-10⁻⁸) c. In fact a smaller version of your experiment could happen in CERN if the beam deflection system hypothetically failed in an instant and a bunch of  protons hit a wall. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Hadron_Collider), one bunch contains 115 billion 6.5 TeV protons, thus having overall energy of 120 kJ. I guess this would punch a hole through a wall, not speaking there may be total 2000 bunches in a ring. We have made a real sci-fi particle gun; fortunately not portable.

Comment: Stopping power for protons at this energy seems to be roughly on the order of 3MeVcm^2/g, so they would be stopped by roughly the first 2m of water equivalent atmosphere, although one would have to consider the possibility that the wave of gamma radiation may push some of the atmosphere out of the way, so that the fireball may actually reach the ground. That would be an interesting simulation (and perfectly legal in most parts of the world).

Comment: "Illegal in most countries..."   Let's worry about the energy required to get such a large mass up to   $ v= \frac{c}{2}$  first!